# SQL Server High Availability on premise - cloud

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure, azure-sql-database, high-availability

I would like to know which is the best way to make a copy and keep the copies synchronized of a on premises SQL Server 2008 (not R2) database to SQL Azure.

Think of the SQL Azure as a failover kind of structure...

Notes:

- The database runs fine in SQL Azure
- I have already figured out how to get the rest of the app running on Azure
- Please consider suggestions of the type "Upgrade to SQL Server 2012 because of X" if the gain (reliability, efficiency, time to replicate, etc...) are worth it
- I`m looking for instant replication (as fast as possible)
- Yes it will have to sync back eventually. If the on-premises deploy crash and the cloud get activated and changed, sync back will be necessary, but i think it does not need to be automatic... of it is, better!
- The Database consist of 900+ tables (legacy system)

Comment: What sort of sync timescales are you looking for ? every 5 min ? Daily ? How are you going to manage the failover in app code ? or manually ?

Comment: Does it have to sync back into premise database if it failover occurs ?

Comment: Have you made sure your application runs with load okay in Azure ? Sorry for millions of questions .

Comment: @JamesKn edited, and yes it runs fine under what we call a heavy load...

Answer (score 0):

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/sql-databases/getting-started-w-sql-data-sync/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh456371.aspx

I think the best bet is to use SQL Data Sync, it should give you bidirectional and we use it currently to sync data around the world in terms of datacenters and one local on premise database. It will only give you 5 mins sync timing but this will probably do, otherwise the next best options is to use SQL Server VMs and do the old fashion way. But with SQL Azure Data Sync we have found to be reasonable reliable and been running it for a good six months syncing across 4 database in four data centres in Azure.

Some problems though with it,

- It uses Triggers.
- It will obivously add load and connections to your current SQL Database.
- The new control panel in Azure is a nightmare for it, so I would use the old panel for the moment.
- It is in preview last time I looked, so it might not be 100% suitable
  for you.

I would imagine there is some better third party solutions out there but off the shelf and in Azure SQL Data sync is well worth a look for the situation you a describing.